# Can't operate VNCserver on linux machine - Configurations missing

Tags: networking, kali-linux, vnc, x11vnc

I'm running `vncserver` and getting this prompt:

> New 'Middle:1 (root)' desktop at :1 on machine Middle
>
> starting applications specified in /root/.vnc/xstartup
>     Log file is /root/.vnc/Middle:1.log
>
> Use xtightvncviewer -SecurityTypes VncAuth -passwd /root/.vnc/passwd :1 to    connect to the VNC server.

But when I try to connect using my VNC viewer on my windows machine I get `The connection was refused by the computer`.

This problem happened because I had edited my `/etc/vnc/xstartup` file since I had a grey screen every time I tried to log in the VNC server so I followed every solution I could find but they didn't fix it... Maybe made it worse.

My /etc/vnc/xstartup file:
[image: xstartupfile]

in ragardes to sgargel's answer:
[image]

about the "can't open file Xresources" - its in my /etc/X11/ folder

What can I do ?

Comment: Check if the *vncserver* is running and on which port is binding with `netstat -antpl` . Check your *vncserver* logfile and if there is some firewall rule that reject traffic.

Comment: I have updated my question with the information you need, I cant find the log file where it is specified to be, its not even being created. And I dont have firewall, neither does the vnc viewer machine.
It seem like a vnc server is running, but I cant connect to it, it's something in the configurations that I know nothing about..

Comment: Error seems to be on */etc/.vnc/xstartup* but you attached your  */etc/vnc/xstartup* (without dot). It's a typo  error? In `netstat` seems that vnc isn't listening on 0.0.0.0:5901

Comment: I dont think so, its a directory-lookup type of command.. I saw that in many other tutorials I have seen.. I dont think that is the issue

Comment: If you can connect with *ssh* you can try to use port forward for trying vnc directly on localhost.

Comment: I can SSH, can you briefly explain what do you mean by port forwarding to localhost?

Comment: First of all your sshd server must *AllowTcpForwarding*. Then connect to your server with `ssh user@myserver -L 31337:127.0.0.1:5901` and open VNC to *localhost:31337*

Comment: That worked , I can now connect through VNC, but the screen is all grey, any way to fix that?

Comment: I think the problem of the gray screen needs a new question...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your VNC server is only binding to `localhost`

A way to fix it was shown in [this answer](https://serverfault.com/questions/350527/how-to-specific-listening-ip-of-vnc-server-under-linux) .

Comment: I dont think that is the problem , as I can access from any local IP to the machine without using localhost and ssh tunneling, but the grey screen still appears.. thanks for your help.

Comment: Ok so I have Raspbien Jessie running and VNC is working perfect... guess Linux with R.PI3 isnt the best option for VNCviewer/Server...